# send-keys "fa" should find the next "a" character but it's prompting me for a character to jump-forward to. How can I fix this?

Tags: tmux

I found this great [article](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/04/11/tmux-key-binding-scripting/) from 2013 about binding keys in copy mode to run shell scripts and I'm trying to "port" one of the examples to modern tmux (version 3.3a in my case).

`bind g send "0 f:t:" C-m`

I tried this and noticed that it was prompting me for `a` character to jump to.

By the way, my tmux config file contains:

`setw -g mode-keys vi`

So I'm reading that to mean that the `f` in the `send-keys` command should search forward for the colon character.

Reading the documentation helped me come up with as a simple test case:

`bind-key -T copy-mode-vi g send-keys -X "fa"`

It still prompts me for the character.

Is there some way I can let tmux know to use the `a` as the character to jump to instead of prompting me?

Thank you!